# Setting the default value of a DateTime Property to DateTime.Now inside the System.ComponentModel Default Value Attrbute

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

Does any one know how I can specify the Default value for a DateTime property using the System.ComponentModel DefaultValue Attribute?

for example I try this:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime),DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

And it expects the value to be a constant expression.

This is in the context of using with ASP.NET Dynamic Data.  I do not want to scaffold the DateCreated column but simply supply the DateTime.Now if it is not present.  I am using the Entity Framework as my Data Layer

Cheers.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You cannot do this with an attribute because they are just meta information generated at compile time. Just add code to the constructor to initialize the date if required, create a trigger and handle missing values in the database, or implement the getter in a way that it returns DateTime.Now if the backing field is not initialized.

```
public DateTime DateCreated
{
   get
   {
      return this.dateCreated.HasValue
         ? this.dateCreated.Value
         : DateTime.Now;
   }

   set { this.dateCreated = value; }
}

private DateTime? dateCreated = null;
```

Comment: Thank you, before you edit I went the other way and intercepted the setter.  Cheers for the help :-)

Comment: A `get` part can be simplified to: `return dateCreated ?? DateTime.Now;`

Comment: This solution might be a problem in case you want your classes as POCO. In my case, my class should be as clear as POCO class to be transferred via WCF.

Comment: Works for CodeFirst but Not a workable solution for Database First Approach

Comment: If you are using MYSql and this code snippet (which does work) is generating the error `Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754822/unable-to-convert-mysql-date-time-value-to-system-datetime

Comment: @zHs This worked great for me using Database First with Entity Framework.

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44070375/4300463) if you came here for an attribute.

Comment: It appears this doesn't set the value so if the value is retrieved more than once, it would give different values.Try                 if (!_createdDate.HasValue)
                    _createdDate = DateTime.Now;
                return _createdDate.Value;  This would set the value only once.

Answer (score 95):

Add below to the DateTime property

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for and it should get higher up. Many of the other answers do add the current date when inserting an entity, however it doesn't affect the schema(i.e. make getdate() the default value). The issue for me was when I wanted to add a record directly into the table(using SQL) I had to provide the date(or leave it NULL). This is a much better solution. Thanks.

Comment: .Computed is for Add and Update actions. Use .Identity for Add only.

Comment: Best answer by far: it should be added that a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema should be added for the DatabaseGenerated annotation

Comment: What time zone will be used? Will it be UTC?

Comment: Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with codefirst migrations, unfortunately this doesn't do anything :( I upvoted because it's a great answer but doesn't work for my circumstance

Answer (score 55):

I have tested this on **EF core 2.1**

Here you cannot use either Conventions or Data Annotations. You must use the **Fluent API**.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
    }
}
```

[**Official doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, however since my property was on a BaseClass, I couldn't (it created a new table for the BaseClass). Inspecting the ChangeTracker [using this link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/set-created-and-modified-date-in-efcore.aspx) solved it however (setting both Created and Updated timestamps).

Comment: What if "Created" property is in a base class that is not used to create a separate table for it? Do I need to do for every derived classes that inherit from that base class?

Answer (score 33):

There's no reason I can come up with that it shouldn't be possible to do through an attribute. It might be in Microsoft's backlog. Who knows.

The best solution I have found is to use the defaultValueSql parameter in the code first migration.

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.SomeTable",
    c => new
        {
            TheDateField = c.DateTime(defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()")
        });
```

I don't like the often reference solution of setting it in the entity class constructor because if anything other than Entity Framework sticks a record in that table, the date field won't get a default value. And the idea of using a trigger to handle that case just seems wrong to me.

Comment: in case of altering and adding nullable use AddColumn("dbo.table", "Created",   c =>  c.DateTime(
                    nullable:true,          
                    defaultValueSql:"getdate()" 
                    ) );

Comment: It's not good idea, if you will choose your db, you need refactor this code.

Comment: Woudn't it be best to use both the constructor and the defaultValueSql, so your class works both with and without the EF?

Answer (score 17):

It is possible and quite simple:

for `DateTime.MinValue`

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(typeof(DateTime), "")]
```

for any other value as last argument of `DefaultValueAttribute` specify string that represent desired DateTime value.

This value must be constant expression and is required to create object (`DateTime`) using `TypeConverter`.

Comment: I'd like to believe that usage work for me but unfortunately it did not. Migration result;
`defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)`

Comment: Just tried to put a string date ( "1/1/20" ) instead of empty string  and it converts it successfully.

Comment: Well, sure, but ... the actual question is about setting it to the current datetime. Which, afaik, has to be done either in Fluent API (which I hate) or in the database.

Answer (score 16):

Just found this looking for something different, but in the new C# version, you can use an even shorter version for that:

```
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Awesome answer, just what I wanted

Comment: Is this _always_ safe to use?

Comment: can't think of any drawbacks, official documentation says little about auto-initialization https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: Is it posible to add date format? like: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhh")

Comment: If you want a string-property instead of DateTime, then yes, you can add your code to the initializer.

Comment: If the database and the web application runs on different servers with different date settings, then it wont always be safe to use.

Comment: This answer should be more upvoted.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution if you are using the Entity Framework is the add a partical class and define a constructor for the entity as the framework does not define one.  For example if you have an entity named Example you would put the following code in a seperate file.

```
namespace EntityExample
{
    public partial class Example : EntityObject
    {
        public Example()
        {
            // Initialize certain default values here.
            this._DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant (and probably also the intended) solution to the problem. But this is assuming people are using EF Code First.

Comment: This is how I do it, until I realized that adding a complex property to my entity causes EF to generate a default constructor, leaving me with no way to write my own...

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest solution is to set

```
Created DATETIME2 NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

in column declaration and in VS2010 EntityModel designer set corresponding column property **StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed**.

Comment: If I do it like this and make the property nullable, I get an EDMX validation error, because a non-nullable column is mapped to a nullable property.

Comment: If you're using EDMX, then you're not using EF Core

Answer (score 5):

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Please check [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new attribute class is a good suggestion. In my case, I wanted to specify 'default(DateTime)' or 'DateTime.MinValue' so that the Newtonsoft.Json serializer would ignore DateTime members without real values.

```
[JsonProperty( DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore )]
[DefaultDateTime]
public DateTime EndTime;

public class DefaultDateTimeAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
{
    public DefaultDateTimeAttribute()
        : base( default( DateTime ) ) { }

    public DefaultDateTimeAttribute( string dateTime )
        : base( DateTime.Parse( dateTime ) ) { }
}
```

Without the DefaultValue attribute, the JSON serializer would output "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" even though the DefaultValueHandling.Ignore option was set.

Answer (score 4):

Simply consider setting its value in the constructor of your entity class

```
public class Foo
{
       public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
       public Foo()
       {
           DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
       }

}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Although I had to set the `Datetime` property nullable before doing this.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, but the one which works for me best is below:

```
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed a UTC Timestamp as a default value and so modified Daniel's solution like this:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    [XmlAttribute]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    [Display(Name = "Date Modified")]
    [DateRange(Min = "1900-01-01", Max = "2999-12-31")]
    public DateTime DateModified {
        get { return dateModified; }
        set { dateModified = value; } 
    }
    private DateTime dateModified = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
```

For DateRangeAttribute tutorial, see [this awesome blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

There is a way. Add these classes:

DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Custom.Extensions;

namespace Custom.DefaultValueAttributes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class's DefaultValue attribute allows the programmer to use DateTime.Now as a default value for a property.
    /// Inspired from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/A-flexible-Default-Value-11c2db19. 
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
    {
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
        private object _value;

        public override object Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (_value == null)
                    return _value = GetDefaultValue();

                return _value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialized a new instance of this class using the desired DateTime value. A string is expected, because the value must be generated at runtime.
        /// Example of value to pass: Now. This will return the current date and time as a default value. 
        /// Programmer tip: Even if the parameter is passed to the base class, it is not used at all. The property Value is overridden.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="defaultValue">Default value to render from an instance of <see cref="DateTime"/></param>
        public DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute(string defaultValue) : base(defaultValue)
        {
            DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        }

        public static DateTime GetDefaultValue(Type objectType, string propertyName)
        {
            var property = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute), false)
                ?.Cast<DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute>()
                ?.FirstOrDefault();

            return attribute.GetDefaultValue();
        }

        private DateTime GetDefaultValue()
        {
            // Resolve a named property of DateTime, like "Now"
            if (this.IsProperty)
            {
                return GetPropertyValue();
            }

            // Resolve a named extension method of DateTime, like "LastOfMonth"
            if (this.IsExtensionMethod)
            {
                return GetExtensionMethodValue();
            }

            // Parse a relative date
            if (this.IsRelativeValue)
            {
                return GetRelativeValue();
            }

            // Parse an absolute date
            return GetAbsoluteValue();
        }

        private bool IsProperty
            => typeof(DateTime).GetProperties()
                .Select(p => p.Name).Contains(this.DefaultValue);

        private bool IsExtensionMethod
            => typeof(DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute).Assembly
                .GetType(typeof(DefaultDateTimeExtensions).FullName)
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false))
                .Select(p => p.Name).Contains(this.DefaultValue);

        private bool IsRelativeValue
            => this.DefaultValue.Contains(":");

        private DateTime GetPropertyValue()
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<DateTime>();
            var value = (DateTime)instance.GetType()
                .GetProperty(this.DefaultValue)
                .GetValue(instance);

            return value;
        }

        private DateTime GetExtensionMethodValue()
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<DateTime>();
            var value = (DateTime)typeof(DefaultDateTimeValueAttribute).Assembly
                .GetType(typeof(DefaultDateTimeExtensions).FullName)
                .GetMethod(this.DefaultValue)
                .Invoke(instance, new object[] { DateTime.Now });

            return value;
        }

        private DateTime GetRelativeValue()
        {
            TimeSpan timeSpan;
            if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(this.DefaultValue, out timeSpan))
            {
                return default(DateTime);
            }

            return DateTime.Now.Add(timeSpan);
        }

        private DateTime GetAbsoluteValue()
        {
            DateTime value;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(this.DefaultValue, out value))
            {
                return default(DateTime);
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

DefaultDateTimeExtensions.cs

```
using System;

namespace Custom.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Inspired from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/A-flexible-Default-Value-11c2db19. See usage for more information.
    /// </summary>
    public static class DefaultDateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static DateTime FirstOfYear(this DateTime dateTime)
            => new DateTime(dateTime.Year, 1, 1, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond);

        public static DateTime LastOfYear(this DateTime dateTime)
            => new DateTime(dateTime.Year, 12, 31, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond);

        public static DateTime FirstOfMonth(this DateTime dateTime)
            => new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1, dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond);

        public static DateTime LastOfMonth(this DateTime dateTime)
            => new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month), dateTime.Hour, dateTime.Minute, dateTime.Second, dateTime.Millisecond);
    }
}
```

And use DefaultDateTimeValue as an attribute to your properties. Value to input to your validation attribute are things like "Now", which will be rendered at run time from a DateTime instance created with an Activator. The source code is inspired from this thread: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/A-flexible-Default-Value-11c2db19. I changed it to make my class inherit with DefaultValueAttribute instead of a ValidationAttribute.

Answer (score 2):

In C# Version 6 it's possible to provide a default value

```
public DateTime fieldname { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The same as Brandtware’s answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47528230/52277

Answer (score 2):

Using `EntityTypeConfiguration`, I get it like this:

```
public class UserMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        builder.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        builder.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
        builder.Property(u => u.Status).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.Password).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(u => u.Registration).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

        builder.HasMany(u => u.DrawUser).WithOne(u => u.User);

        builder.ToTable("User");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the Fluent API, in OnModelCreating function in your Context class add following.

```
 builder.Property(u => u.CreatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
 builder.Property(u => u.UpdatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

Note I'm using a separate type configuration class. If you did right in the function would be like:

```
builder.Enitity<User>().Property(u => u.CreatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Answer (score 0):

How you deal with this at the moment depends on what model you are using Linq to SQL or EntityFramework?

In L2S you can add

```
public partial class NWDataContext
{
    partial void InsertCategory(Category instance)
    {
        if(Instance.Date == null)
            Instance.Data = DateTime.Now;

        ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance);
    }
}
```

EF is a little more complicated see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714.aspx for more info on EF buisiness logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public DateTime DateCreated
{
   get
   {
      return (this.dateCreated == default(DateTime))
         ? this.dateCreated = DateTime.Now
         : this.dateCreated;
   }

   set { this.dateCreated = value; }
}
private DateTime dateCreated = default(DateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old, but a have a suggestion that may help some.

I used an Enum to determine what to set in the attribute constructor.

Property declaration :

```
[DbProperty(initialValue: EInitialValue.DateTime_Now)]
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

Property constructor :

```
Public Class DbProperty Inherits System.Attribute

    Public Property InitialValue As Object

    Public Sub New(ByVal initialValue As EInitialValue)
       Select Case initialValue
          Case EInitialValue.DateTime_Now
             Me.InitialValue = System.DateTime.Now

          Case EInitialValue.DateTime_Min
             Me.InitialValue = System.DateTime.MinValue

          Case EInitialValue.DateTime_Max
             Me.InitialValue = System.DateTime.MaxValue

       End Select

    End Sub
End Class
```

Enum :

```
Public Enum EInitialValue
   DateTime_Now
   DateTime_Min
   DateTime_Max
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can do this using `StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity` (set in the model designer properties window).

I wouldn't have guessed that would be how to do it, but while trying to figure it out I noticed that some of my date columns were already defaulting to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` and some weren't. Checking the model, I see that the only difference between the two columns besides the name is that the one getting the default value has `StoreGeneratedPattern` set to `Identity`.

I wouldn't have expected that to be the way, but reading the description, it sort of makes sense:

> Determines if the corresponding column in the database will be auto-generated during insert and update operations.

Also, while this does make the database column have a default value of "now", I guess it does not actually set the property to be `DateTime.Now` in the POCO. This hasn't been an issue for me as I have a customized .tt file that already sets all of my date columns to `DateTime.Now` automatically (it's actually not hard to modify the .tt file yourself, especially if you have ReSharper and get a syntax highlighting plugin. (Newer versions of VS may already syntax highlight .tt files, not sure.))

The issue for me was: how do I get the database column to have a default so that existing queries that omit that column will still work? And the above setting worked for that.

I haven't tested it yet but it's also possible that setting this will interfere with setting your own explicit value. (I only stumbled upon this in the first place because EF6 Database First wrote the model for me this way.)

Answer (score 0):

below works in .NET 5.0

```
        private DateTime _DateCreated= DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime DateCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DateCreated;
            }

            set { this._DateCreated = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using the DatabaseGenerated attribute, example

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultValueAttribute` class can be subclassed. E.g.

```
public class DefaultDateTimeAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute
{
    public DefaultDateTimeAttribute() : base (DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```
[DefaultDateTime]
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -9):

I also wanted this and came up with this solution (I'm only using the date part - a default time makes no sense as a PropertyGrid default):

```
public class DefaultDateAttribute : DefaultValueAttribute {
  public DefaultDateAttribute(short yearoffset)
    : base(DateTime.Now.AddYears(yearoffset).Date) {
  }
}
```

This just creates a new attribute that you can add to your DateTime property.
E.g. if it defaults to DateTime.Now.Date:

```
[DefaultDate(0)]
```

Comment: WARNING!!!!!! this is very bad and should be removed from SO. I just spent hours debugging issues caused by this suggestion.

At first glance, it looks good and seems to work. But this is a trap.

Attributes require static values for a reason. They are initialized once. After that, the value changes.

So while the first instance you create will look fine, and subsequent instances will look fine, they all actually use the first value.

Once your app has been running for awhile, you'll notice the issue and wonder why. And in debug, when you run it for a minute, it will run fine.

BEWARE!

Comment: Chris is right.  I found the same problem.  _Do not use this answer_.