# EntityFramework 4 - Updating records in foreach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I am creating an app which is using EF4 and DBContext to access the backend database.

At one point in the application I pull back a set of records and iterate them, updating the value and a timestamp.

Code:

```js
// update any notified parameters...
foreach (RecvParam parameter in RecvParameters)
{
    // get the existing parameter
    Data.DeviceParameter dbParameter = this.device.DeviceParameters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == parameter.Name);

    // null check
    if (dbParameter == null)
        continue;

    // update an existing parameter instance
    dbParameter.Value = parameter.Value;
    dbParameter.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;

    // add an entry to the context
    DBContext.Entry(dbParameter).State = EntityState.Modified;        
}

DBContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I do this, my database values do not change... the timestamps and value fields stay the same.

Could someone possibly point me in the right direction...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042327/entity-framework-storegeneratedpattern-computed-property-problem

My problem was actually hidden within this question/answer...

The computed propety of StoreGeneratedPattern meant the the field couldnt be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not required to update the state of your entities manually. Modifying a property of an entity that is attached to a context does the job for you.

Anyway, if `device` is your database context, you must call `SaveChanges` on it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042327/entity-framework-storegeneratedpattern-computed-property-problem

My problem was actually hidden within this question/answer...

The computed propety of StoreGeneratedPattern meant the the field couldnt be updated.