# Entity Framework and nullable fields

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm using EF (v5) against an existing database that has a large number of nullable fields with default values.

When inserting a new entity, if no value has been specified for a nullable field, null will be inserted (the database default will not be used). That makes sense in that EF can't determine if I really intended null or not.

If I set the fields to be `StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed` however, it will use the default value on insert, however it will only *ever* use the default value. If I supply my own value (even on `Update`), the value seems be ignored.

Is there a way for this scenario to work without making changes to the underlying database?

Example of the process I'm following:

```
var myEntity = databaseSession.MyEntities.Single(x => x.EntityID = 123);
myEntity.SomeField = 1;
databaseSession.SaveChanges();
```

`SomeField` in this case is of type `int?` and is set to `StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed`

Using EFProf, I can see the SQL query being issued is:

```
update [dbo].[MyEntities]
set    @p = 0
where  ([EntityID] = 123 /* @0 */)
```

Adding:

```
databaseSession.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```

Causes an update statement to be generated that updates all fields in the table but crucially, it does not include any fields that are set to `StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed`

Comment: Could you show an example of how your updating a value, and submitting to the db

Comment: Can you try adding this `databaseSession.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myEntity, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);`

Comment: @msarchet question updated again...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042327/entity-framework-storegeneratedpattern-computed-property-problem take a look at that

Comment: The only way will be to customize EDMX file, set default value in EDMX and customize text template to set as default values in property definition inside class. I have done this.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that computed columns really aren't meant to be set manually.

If that works for you, you may simply set the properties to their default values in the default constructor of the entity;  it's what it's there for, and you have the extra advantage that you will see those values even before the call to SaveChanges.

**Update:** [Relevant suggestion](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first).