# EF 4.1 in MVC 3 - Date from form submission overwriting default in DB

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

So I have a small table and one of the columns is a date, with a a default GETDATE() constraint for use as a timestamp.

Neither the model, nor the ViewModel have a property for this date, but I have an edmx file, so obviously it does.  I don't capture the date at any point in the app.

The issue is that when the changes are submitted to the db, the model contains the date '0001-01-01' and this is overwriting the default in the db.

Is there some way to ignore date from the client side?

Comment: Can't you just remove the property from the mapping if you don't use it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [StoreGeneratedPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern.aspx) to `Computed` on that property in the EDMX. See a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042327/entity-framework-storegeneratedpattern-computed-property-problem).

Comment: That was it, thanks.  I dont have enuff rep to vote for your answer but I am making a list and will come back through when I do.