# Is there any way to change value of field set to "StoreGeneratedPattern=Computed"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an `int` field in my table set to `default 0`. I set this field's `StoreGeneratedPattern` as `Computed`, but I can't change the value of this field after using `SaveChanges()`.
I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5042357/9497111) on same problem, just wondering if there is any better way to do that.

**Edit**

here is the edmx generated from database (entity framework 6)

[image]

this is the result after adding (from my application) some data to table `Intervention` and as you see IsDeleted set to 0 because of `IsDeleted int default 0`

[image]

and

[image]

*But* after trying something like that

```
 db.Interventions.Find(currentInterv).IsDeleted = 1;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

its just didn't work because of StoreGeneratedPattern=Computed

Comment: Can you post the table's schema along with some sample data and expected results? @driwand

Comment: Also what version of EF, and whether this is Code-First metadata, or EDMX-based metadata.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EDMX-based EF6 the only thing you can do is use a store query to change the column value.  With code-first you can create an additional DbContext subtype with different mapping metadata.

But IsDeleted probably shouldn't be StoreGenerated.  You can default it to 0 in the database, and in the Entity model by just declaring it as `int` and not `int?`.

Comment: well changing int? to int and set StoreGenerated to none solved the problem. but for datetime (also set default value in database's table) I m getting something like this https://i.imgur.com/3t6onSZ.png

Comment: That's because that's .NET's default value.  You can change it by during SaveChanges as in the answer you linked.