# EF CodeFirst: Rails-style created and modified columns

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, data-annotations

Using Entity Framework CodeFirst, how do I create a created datetime column that gets populated with the current timestamp everytime a record is inserted for that table, and a modified datetime column that has a timestamp generated evertime a row is updated?  Rails does this by default and I was hoping the EF generated database would have this as well, but it doesn't.  Is this something that can be done with data annotations?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported in EF. EF will not create these columns for you automatically. You must do it yourselves by either:

- Have `Created` and `Modified` properties in every entity where you want to maintain these values. You must also manually maintain these columns in your application ([common approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500464/how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-property-when-saving-using-code-first-ef4-1/5503294#5503294) is overriding `SaveChanges` and set values accordingly).
- If you don't need these values mapped (you never expect to use them in your application and you are happy with the logic in the database) you can create [custom database initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702) which would execute your custom SQL to alter tables and add those columns, default constraints for `Created` columns and update triggers for `Modified` columns.

Comment: Pefect!  Thank you!  Just to be clear, though, there's no way to accomplish this with data annotations?

Comment: No because data annotations do not add additional logic to maintain value in the those properties and currently EF don't allow you adding custom annotations.