# How to deal with modified entity records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

At the moment to check for changes with my entity framework object, I check in the database and I go through each object and compare the properties with the updated, if they are updated then my date modified will be updated as well.

I find that it's getting very lengthy in code and was wondering if there's a cleaner way to check for changes using entity framework. I was thinking maybe using deepcopy with a object comparison and compare something like below. But I would have to set each of my tables to be serialized and I don't know if that's a good thing.

```
if (Equals(oldentity, newentity))
{
    newentity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
}
```

My current method of tracking changes

```
if (oldentity.firstname != newentity.firstname || oldentity.lastname != newentity.lastname)
{
    newentity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now
}
```

The if statement is a snippet, my entity has many properties so it gets lengthy...

Comment: Shouldn't the modified date always be updated any time the entity is persisted, regardless of what values changed?

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework ? If so, `EntityState` should tell you if an entity has been modified, if not then I'd use reflection to loop through all properties and compare.

Comment: You can look at this answer how to [check in a generic way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29995396/3790486) all properties of an entity.

Comment: Hi @FrancisDucharme I am using entity framework but I also have a layer of UnitOfWork repository pattern ontop of it.

Comment: @Master Sorry, not familiar with UoW concept but I believe you should still be able to track changes with the context (`newentity.EntityState`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your entity an interface with `CreatedDate` and `ModifiedDate` properties:

```
public interface ITrackedEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate    { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedDate   { get; set; }
}
```

Then override `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` in the `DBContext` to handle updating the properties for added and modified entities automatically:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.UpdateTrackedEntities();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    this.UpdateTrackedEntities();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void UpdateTrackedEntities()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is ITrackedEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((ITrackedEntity)entity.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        ((ITrackedEntity)entity.Entity).ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: The idea behind this can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16557167/188246).

Comment: Hi David, I feel this would update modified anytime entity is persisted. I'm trying to have it update only when properties have been updated. Unless I'm understanding the code wrong?

Comment: @Master I think if the entity hasn't been modified it will have a state of `EntityState.Unchanged`, but I haven't run a test to check for sure. The check `x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified` should only update added or modified entities.

Comment: Sweet jesus it worked! Thank you. It definitely worked how I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
public bool HasUnsavedChanges(MyObject oldentity)
{
    return (YourObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified).Any(x=>x.Id == oldentity.Id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework has a ChangeTracker in DbContext.

I for example have a override of my context's SaveChanges() and it is able to get all the changes made in my entities.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    var addedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
    var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
    var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

    //Save info generating the ids
    var ret = base.SaveChanges();

    //Generate Logs logic
    ...

    return ret;
}
```

ChangeTracker also accepts an entity as parameter if you want to check a just a single entity for changes.

More info on ChangeTracker (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker(v=vs.113).aspx)