# Create default values in Entityframe work 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am creating tables using code first and I have column called CreatedDate, I want this column to have a default value of GETDATE().

But I don't want to do this is in the migration script like below

```
AddColumn("Agents", "CreatedDate", n => n.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"));
```

How can I do this in the Mapping or in the model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to set the default value in the POCO, you can set it in the [property backing field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691035/setting-the-default-value-of-a-datetime-property-to-datetime-now-inside-the-syst) or in the constructor as follow.

## 1. Constructor

```
public class Agent
{
    public Agent()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

## 2. Property Backing Field

```
public class Agent
{
    private DateTime _createdDate;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _createdDate == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.Now : _createdDate; }
        set { _createdDate = value; }
    }
}
```