# How can I alter a model to set the SQL default date when using EF code migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Firstly, there are a lot of answers in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691035/setting-the-default-value-of-a-datetime-property-to-datetime-now-inside-the-syst) that are of a similar ilk which helped me get very close, but none quite work in my situation.

I have a model class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TestModelId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

And this is added to a `DbContext` file like so:

```
public virtual DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }
```

So on `add-migration` this produces:

```
...
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "TestModels",
    columns: table => new 
    {
        TestModelId = table.Column<int>(nullable:false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        CreatedOn = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable:false)
    },
    ...
```

Now I'm trying to get a one-stop place to make sure the `CreatedOn` column builder has the default `GETDATE()` in there:

```
CreatedOn = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable:false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()")
```

which I know works perfectly when translating it to the SQL Server side, but I've tried several data annotation and constructor versions as per the linked question to no avail e.g. the attribute

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

does nothing and I don't want to have to manually add the `defaultValueSql` part to the migration file every time I create one / it.

So where can I do this in the models?

Comment: While you're at it - get in the habit of using `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` to get the current date. The old legacy `GETDATE()` only ever returns a `DATETIME` with all its limitations - `SYSDATETIME()` is the more modern, more precise, more flexible version to achieve the same thing that fully supports the "new" date and date/time datatypes we have since SQL Server **2008** .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that in the DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           modelBuilder.Property(x => x.CreatedOn).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
           .....
        });
```

edit: needed to have the entity property of the modelBuilder in there too:

`modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>().Property...`

Comment: Ok that was a good hint but missing the reference to the `Entity` itself, I figured it out though, thanks!

Comment: Oops... that's what happens when you type code in the box itself. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: ha I actually figured that's what had happened but it was basically spot on answer anyway