# Generate an unique string for a field in a pre-defined pattern when save using Code First Approch: Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table called ***Quotations*** and it has an unique string field called ***QuotationNo***.

```
public class Quotation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } //PK
    public string QuotationNo{ get; set; } // Pattern QUOT/12-22/00001 => QUOT + MONTH-YEAR + PrimaryKey.ToStrin("5d");
}
```

So I have implemented it by calling **_db.SaveChanges()** method twice as follows.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     _db.Quotations.Add(quot);
     _db.SaveChanges(); // 1 time saving
    
     quot.QuotationNo= "QUOT/" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM/") + quot.Id.ToString("D5");
     _db.Quotations.Update(quot);
     _db.SaveChanges(); // 2 time saving
}
```

Is there a short way to do this?

Comment: Store the date created and use a computed column in the database.

Comment: That's easier. Thanks!! I will create a virtual property with the getter having that logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this method is more clear.

Step 1: Creating new field in the table to store **DateCreated**.

Step 2: Making **QuotationNo** a virtual and [NotMapped field](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx), which is always a calculated/generated field.

See the code

```
public class Quotation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } //PK
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } //New field to store quotation created date.
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual string? QuotationNo  //Ax Key(Quotation No: QUOT/01-22/0000001=> PQTN/mmYY/0000000)
    {
         get
         {
             return $"QUOT/{this.DateCreated:dd-MM/}{PolyCostingId:D5}"; 
         }
         set
         {
             this.PolyCostingCode = value;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public class Quotation
{
    public int Id { get; set; } //PK
    public string QuotationNo
            {
                get
                {
                    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.QuotationNo)
                       ? $"QUOT/{DateTime.Today:dd-MM:hh:mm:ss/}{Id:D7}"
                       : this.QuotationNo;
                }

                set { this.QuotationNo = value; }
            }}
```

For example

```
var x = new Quotation();
x.Id = 12345;
var quotationNo = x.QuotationNo; 
// quotationNo will be QUOT/22-12/0012345
```

Some reference here [Setting the default value of a DateTime Property to DateTime.Now inside the System.ComponentModel Default Value Attrbute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691035/setting-the-default-value-of-a-datetime-property-to-datetime-now-inside-the-syst)

Comment: dd-MM are not saved in the database here? I think setter should be changed.

Comment: Please check the updated answer I add a example for you. ```DateTime.Today:dd-MM/``` is  shortcut for ```DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM/")```

Comment: If the same quotation was viewed next month. The quotation number will be different. It is not what I expected.

Comment: I think you're right. Just thinking how to do it

Comment: @LakshithaKanchana Could you try my updated answer, I add second to test it

Comment: Sorry, took long to discover, there is an issue with {Id:D7} section. Because Id is the primary key auto increment type, it is generated by the DB itself. So {Id:D7} always be 0000000?